# How to schedule backups in SQL Server 2008 Web Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-backup

I have a SQL Server 2008 Web Edition and I used the

> Management > Management Plans > Wizrd to schedule the backup of all my databases.

I executred the task to test it and I get this error:

> Executed as user: WIN-343434\SYSTEM.
>   Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute
>   Package Utility  Version 10.0.1600.22
>   for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.
>   The SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>   requires Integration Services to be
>   installed by one of these editions of
>   SQL Server 2008: Standard, Enterprise,
>   Developer, or Evaluation. To install
>   Integration Services, run SQL Server
>   Setup and select Integration Services.
>   The package execution failed.  The
>   step failed.

How am I supposed to schedule backups in SQL Server 2008 Web Edition? If Web Edition does not support it, then why did the Wizard not say so??

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is reportedly fixed in [**SQL 2008 SP2**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968382/) (or SP1 Cumulative Update 3).  Have a look at [**this Technet article**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961126/) that describes the error you're getting.